# SQL Select the Nth row and group by across multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, subquery, inner-join

At the moment I am stuck with a problem when selecting data from a MYSQL Database.

The main topic is stock management, so I have customers, products and stock movements (putting product from one place in my warehouse to another). The data I need is split across three different tables that are build like this (simplified):

```
tableCustomer
customerID | loginEmail | ...
123 | test@test.com | ...
124 | hello@world.com | ...

tableProduct
productID | customerID | createDate | ...
789 | 123 | 2019-12-12 | ...
790 | 123 | 2019-12-13 | ...
791 | 124 | 2019-12-14 | ...

tableMovement
movementID | productID | createDate | ...
548 | 790 | 2020-01-25 | ...
549 | 789 | 2020-01-27 | ...
550 | 791 | 2020-01-28 | ...
```

What I am trying to find is the createDate of the Nth (like 25th) movement for each customer. The result should be something like

```
customerID | movement.createDate
123 | 2020-01-25
124 | 2020-01-28
```

So it would be a list with every customerID listed once and the createDate of the 25th movement for that customerID. I couldn't find any way to select that result because of the different tables. Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Walk me through how you get that result from the published data. And if you don't then amend question so that you do.

Answer (score 1):

One option uses a correlated subquery and a row-limiting clause:

```
select c.customerid,
    (
        select m.createdate
        from movement m
        inner join product p on p.productid = m.productid
        where m.customerid = c.customerid
        order by m.createdate
        limit 24, 1
    )
from customer c
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you. Just had to make a little change in the where-clause, because you used m.customerid, but it needs to be p.customerid, because the movement does not have a customerID.